# setBackGroundRGB not accepting string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The class `setBackgroundRGB()` works if I pass it a  literal

```
setBackgroundRGB(255,255,255);
```

but if I pass it a variable instead, it fails:

```
_Color = "255, 255, 255";

setBackgroundRGB(_Color);
```

Does not work and returns an error

```
`Cannot find method setBackgroundRGB(string)`
```

Do i need to do some kind of conversion here that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the API does not have a method setBackgroundRGB(string), provides a method [setBackgroundRGB(Integer, Integer, Integer)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setBackgroundRGB%28Integer,Integer,Integer%29), however, an option to achieve what you need, having a string as input is:

```
function setColorToRange() {
  var colorRGB = '0, 255, 0';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();      
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B3');
  range.setBackgroundRGB.apply(range, colorRGB.split(', '));
}
```

**UPDATE**

To get the vector can be applied several improvements, widening a little the example presented, we integrate some of the improvements indicated in the comments, resulting in the following:

```
function setColorToRange() {
  var colorRGB = '0, 255, 0';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();      
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B3');
  var arrColorRGB = getRGB(RGBString);
  range.setBackgroundRGB.apply(range, arrColorRGB);
}

function getRGB(RGBString) {
  // Returns a vector of integers
  return RGBString.replace(/ /g, '').split(',').map(returnInt);
}

function returnInt(value) {
  return parseInt(value, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an array.  The following should work:

```
_Color = [255, 255, 255];
setBackgroundRGB(_Color);
```

Note - this is essentially what the post above is doing -- split() converts strings to arrays...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string. It takes integers.

Try This:

```
_Color = 255,255,255
```

I doubt that will work however. You may need to do multiple variables for each

```
red = 255;
green = 255;
blue = 255;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another variant of the same approach using **range** and **RGBstring** as parameters :

```
function test(){ // to define 2 parameters
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:B3');
  setColorToRange(range,'0, 255, 0');
}

function setColorToRange(range,RGBString) {
  var colorRGB = RGBString.replace(/ /g,'').split(',');// first remove spaces if present then split on comma only to get the array of integers
  range.setBackgroundRGB.apply(range, colorRGB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const rgb = {
red : 224,
green : 224,
blue : 224
}

....setBackgroundRGB(rgb.red, rgb.green, rgb.blue);

Comment: A 'good answer' also includes a sentence or two in plain text that explains why you think your solution will work. Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer